# Multiple conditional callbacks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback, conditional-statements

I have an asynchronous function that may or may not call some other asynchronous functions and should call it's callback when all of the child functions are done.
I'm not happy with my what I came up with and feel like there should be an easier way. What's to proper way of doing this (without libraries)?

```js
function fn(callback)
{
  let pendingOperations = 0;

  if (condition1)
  {
    ++pendingOperations;
  }

  if (condition2)
  {
    ++pendingOperations;
  }

  if (pendingOperations === 0)
  {
    callback();
  }
  else
  {
    if (condition1)
    {
      otherFunction1(() =>
      {
        if (--pendingOperations <= 0)
        {
          callback();
        }
      });
    }

    if (condition2)
    {
      otherFunction2(() =>
      {
        if (--pendingOperations <= 0)
        {
          callback();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Read about Promises (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`Promise`s**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for this type of work:

```
function fn(callback) {
    let promises = [];
    if (condition1) {
        promises.push(new Promise(resolve => otherFunction1(resolve)));
    }
    if (condition2) {
        promises.push(new Promise(resolve => otherFunction2(resolve)));
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(callback);
}
```

If `promises` is empty (due to both `condition1` and `condition2` failing), then the promise returned by `Promise.all(promises)` will be resolved immediately and thus `callback` is called immediately.